# Using 2 differently sized lists to make key, values in a dict

Tags: python

The challenge that I'm facing is trying to figure out how to use 2 lists for a dict with one list having less items than the other. For each item in the list `names`, I'd like to add the item as a key in the `combos` dict while also adding one item from the `answers` list as a value to the key.. but once the smaller list reaches it's end adding values I'd like to restart from the beginning until every key has a value.

It's hard for me to google an answer because I can't really figure out how to accurately describe my question.

```
names = ["one", "two", "three"]
answers = ["yes", "no"]

combos = {}

def do_something():
    #do stuff
    print(combos)

do_something()
```

Desired output:

```
{"one": "yes", "two": "no", "three": "yes"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) is meant for exactly this kind of challenge:

```
from itertools import cycle

names = ["one", "two", "three"]
answers = ["yes", "no"]

combos = dict(zip(names, cycle(answers)))

print(combos)
# {'one': 'yes', 'two': 'no', 'three': 'yes'}
```

Given an iterable like a list, it will just keep producing values in order. Since `zip()` stops when the last iterable runs out, it stops producing values when `names` has nothing left.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
names = ["one", "two", "three"]
answers = ["yes", "no"]


from itertools import cycle
d = dict(zip(names, cycle(answers)))
```

Output:

```
{'one': 'yes', 'two': 'no', 'three': 'yes'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The modulo (%) function is great for repeating lists

```
names = ["one", "two", "three"]
answers = ["yes", "no"]

combos = {}


def do_something():
    for i, name in enumerate(names):
        combos[name] = answers[i % len(answers)]
    print(combos)


do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a dictionary comprehension

```py
result = {name: answers[i % len(answers)] for i,name in enumerate(names)}
```